Existence of specific semisimple element
Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a complex semisimple Lie algebra. Choose a Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$ and corresponding set of simple roots $\Delta$. Show that there exists $H\in\mathfrak{h}$ such that $\alpha(H)=2$ for each $\alpha\in\Delta$.
I don't know how to prove this. Any help would be appreciated.

If $\Delta$ is a set of simple roots, then by definition, $\Delta$ is a basis of $\mathfrak h^*$ and if $\mathbb Z_{\geq 0} \Delta = \{\sum_{\gamma \in \Delta} n_{\gamma} \gamma: n_{\gamma} \in\mathbb Z_{\geq 0}\}$, we have $\Phi= \Phi^+\cup (-\Phi^+)$ where $\Phi^+ = \Phi\cap \mathbb Z_{\geq 0} \Delta$.
Now $\mathfrak h$ is finite-dimensional, hence the canonical map $d\colon \mathfrak h \to (\mathfrak h^*)^*$ is an isomorphism, and since there is a unique linear functional on $\mathfrak h^*$ satisfying $f(\gamma)=2$ for all $\gamma \in \Delta$, it follows that there is a unique $h \in \mathfrak h$ such that $d(h)=f$, that is, there is a unique $h \in \mathfrak h$ such that $\alpha(h)=2$ for all $\alpha \in \Delta$.
